# Attempted to load class "Command" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Console\Command" Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

The class Command.php was deleted from the project after running somme commands with Command-Prompt
(path= C:\myProject\vendor\symfony\console\Command).

I tried some commands like :
composer require symfony/console

but the error persists.

Comment: If it's just that file missing then perhaps you can just recreate it? https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/7.0/Command/Command.php pick your version. But it could be many reasons you get that error

Comment: "after running somme commands" - what does that mean?

Comment: Did you remove some composer dependecy and lost Component\Console or did you remove this file by mistake ? if your vendor was up to date you could just rm -rf ./vendor and run composer install